# Change and add values in dataframe depending on order ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So my table currently looks like this:

| Roll No | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Math |
| 1 | Science |
| 2 | History |
| 2 | Geography |
| 2 | Politics |
| 3 | FInance |

Based on this I want to add a new column

| Roll No | Subject | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math | Other subject to Math |
| 1 | Science | Math to Science |
| 2 | History | Other subject to History |
| 2 | Geography | History to Geography |
| 2 | Politics | Geography to Politics |
| 3 | Finance | Other subject to Finance |

I am really confused as to how this would be. I am able to write the first instance of a roll no as "Other subject to xyz" but cannot seem to understand how the following values will carry over. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) methods with lambda

```py
df["Details"] = (df.groupby("Roll No")
                    .Subject.transform(lambda x: x.shift()
                    .add(" to ").fillna("Other subject to ") + x))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Roll No    Subject                   Details
0        1       Math     Other subject to Math
1        1    Science           Math to Science
2        2    History  Other subject to History
3        2  Geography      History to Geography
4        2   Politics     Geography to Politics
5        3    Finance  Other subject to Finance
```

Comment: thank you so much! I wanted to know how you approached this? Was this instantly your first thought?

Answer (score 1):

You can use only [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) on columns `"Roll No", "Subject"` then use `numpy.where`.

```
import numpy as np

ss = df['Subject'].shift()
sr = df['Roll No'].shift()
r1 = ss + ' to ' + df['Subject']
r2 = 'Other subject to ' + df['Subject']
df['res'] = np.where(sr==df['Roll No'], r1, r2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Roll No    Subject                       res
0        1       Math     Other subject to Math
1        1    Science           Math to Science
2        2    History  Other subject to History
3        2  Geography      History to Geography
4        2   Politics     Geography to Politics
5        3    FInance  Other subject to FInance
```